# postgresql Idle for transaction while migrating 30GB database

Tags: postgresql, performance, migration, python, postgresql-9.5

I'm migrating part of a mysql database into a **postgresql** database with a different Schema.

I've written a python script, using *mysql-connector* and *psycopg2* modules. It takes care(should) to convert/transform and migrate the database stored files (binary), and its related Metadata into the new postgresql db structure. This is why the operation is a little bit heavy (binary data).

The script proceed as follow:

### Open Databases connections

```
# Mysql connection
try:
    cnx_msql = mysql.connector.connect( host=host_mysql, user=user_mysql, passwd=pswd_mysql, db=dbna_mysql, buffered=True )
except mysql.connector.Error as e:
    print "MYSQL: Unable to connect!", e.msg
    sys.exit(1)

# Postgresql connection
try:
    cnx_psql = psycopg2.connect(**psql_param)
except psycopg2.Error as e:
    print('PSQL: Unable to connect!\n{0}').format(e)
    sys.exit(1)
```

### Perform all the operations without commit (same transaction)

I have to fill 5 postgresql tables, so the following process is (lets say) iterated 5 times (PS: **is not necessary to understand in detail the procedure**):

- Query the source database
- Casting fields types (both metadata fields, and binary field : from bytearray to string)
- Create a new postgresql empty largeobject
- Write the converted byte into the largeobject
- Add into the metadata row the OID generated (this is the relation from metadata to largeobject)

### Commit everything

When everything is done, and only then, I'm going to commit:

```
## Committing
cnx_psql.commit()

## Closing database connections
cnx_msql.close()
cnx_psql.close()
```

## OK then what is the problem?

The script get stuck all the times around the same point, and I don't mean it get stuck because of errors, it seems the script is waiting for system memory in order to continue. I do log all the query while script running, and log stuck as follow in the middle of a query logging: `# cat db-migration/logs/files.py_out`

```
[...]
EXECUTED QUERY : INSERT INTO file_secview (resource_id, version, page, file_oid, iv) VALUES (1442425313047166, 1, 1, NULL, NULL)
lo_migration | new oid : 990844
EXECUTED QUERY : INSERT INTO file_secview (resource_id, version, page, file_oid, iv) VALUES (1288620808802549, 1, 13, NULL, NULL)
lo_migration | new oid : 990845
EXECUTED QUERY : INSERT INTO file_secview (resource_id, version, page, file_oid
```

I'm on a linux CentOS and the RAM memory seems to be full when it happen:

```
# free -h
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           31G        31G       238M       139M        10M        18G
-/+ buffers/cache:        12G        19G 
Swap:         991M         0B       991M
```

looking at the processes with `ps -ef | grep postgres` I find out that postgres is in "idle in transaction state"

```
postgres 10762 15029  0 Jun01 ?        00:03:20 postgres: postgres asw3 ::1(46457) idle in transaction
```

and the python script process is still there waiting to continue:

```
root     10760     1  0 Jun01 ?        00:01:38 db-migration/venv/bin/python ./files.py
```

Currently I'm reading [documentation here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/runtime-config-resource.html) in order to understand if I can edit some configuration parameter in order to fix the issue. Am I reading the correct section? Am I on the right road? I'm not sure what config I have to edit in my case

Does somebody know some better way to debug the problem?

### Edits:

following the requested content of **pg_stat_activity** table:

```
postgres=# SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity;
-[ RECORD 1 ]----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
datid            | 13241
datname          | postgres
pid              | 19421
usesysid         | 10
usename          | postgres
application_name | psql
client_addr      | 
client_hostname  | 
client_port      | -1
backend_start    | 2016-06-02 09:51:12.080112+00
xact_start       | 2016-06-02 09:51:35.269298+00
query_start      | 2016-06-02 09:51:35.269298+00
state_change     | 2016-06-02 09:51:35.269305+00
waiting          | f
state            | active
backend_xid      | 
backend_xmin     | 246599
query            | SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity;
-[ RECORD 2 ]----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
datid            | 91981
datname          | agora3
pid              | 10762
usesysid         | 10
usename          | postgres
application_name | 
client_addr      | ::1
client_hostname  | 
client_port      | 46457
backend_start    | 2016-06-01 15:51:43.105585+00
xact_start       | 2016-06-01 16:01:18.415429+00
query_start      | 2016-06-02 09:45:57.731472+00
state_change     | 2016-06-02 09:45:57.757931+00
waiting          | f
state            | idle in transaction
backend_xid      | 246599
backend_xmin     | 
query            | INSERT INTO file_secview (resource_id, version, page, file_oid, iv) VALUES (1442425299374162, 1, 9, NULL, NULL)
```

I executed again the query, and from there it seems the script is continuing sending the queries, it is not really stuck, mmmh then where the problem lay?:

```
-[ RECORD 2 ]----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
datid            | 91981
datname          | agora3
pid              | 10762
usesysid         | 10
usename          | postgres
application_name | 
client_addr      | ::1
client_hostname  | 
client_port      | 46457
backend_start    | 2016-06-01 15:51:43.105585+00
xact_start       | 2016-06-01 16:01:18.415429+00
query_start      | 2016-06-02 10:12:21.966997+00
state_change     | 2016-06-02 10:12:21.993562+00
waiting          | f
state            | idle in transaction
backend_xid      | 246599
backend_xmin     | 
query            | INSERT INTO file_secview (resource_id, version, page, file_oid, iv) VALUES (1442425299374162, 1, 5, NULL, NULL)
```

Reading psycpg2 documentation I found the following warning:

> By default, any query execution, including a simple SELECT will start
>   a transaction: for long-running programs, if no further action is
>   taken, the session will remain “idle in transaction”, an undesirable
>   condition for several reasons (locks are held by the session, tables
>   bloat...). For long lived scripts, either ensure to terminate a
>   transaction as soon as possible or use an autocommit connection.

I'm thinking I'm going to try to enable autocommit, but how to do it?

Comment: Do you have any connections with the state "waiting" in `pg_stat_activity`? If yes, they are probably waiting for some DDL lock. Check out https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring for some queries to investigate that

Comment: Additionally: there is already a tool that can automate the upgrade from MySQL to Postgres: http://ora2pg.darold.net/ Despite the name, it also works for MySQL, not only Oracle

Comment: Oh and: unless you really know that you want "large objects", using `bytea` is the better choice as a match to a MySQL `BLOB` column

Comment: Many thanks for your comments, I updated the question, there are no connections in "waiting" state. For the ora2pg tool, I'm not sure it can handle a migration with 2 schemas that much different. For the discouragement largeobject usage, I completely agree with you, but developers took that choice, and I currently don't have the power to change that choice since we are already in prod